# MySql Incrementing a cell value with a Unique Key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table with items that can be sorted which looks somewhat like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Position_UNIQUE` (`position`)
)
```

As you can see, position is required to be unique. Now whenever I insert a new record into the table, I'd like it to have the Position #1 thus I need to increment all other values by one.

If I go

```
update mytable set position = position + 1
```

I can enjoy a complaint about my unique key restraint being violated (Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '2' for key 'Position_UNIQUE').

How would I do this the clever way?

Comment: How are you executing the update? in a trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do add an "order by" clause:

```
update mytable set position = position + 1 order by position desc;
```